# Creating methods dynamically in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

I want to do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5;i++)
    {
        public void test[i]()
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }   
    }
```

Can I even create methods like this? I know it requires an array but I have read everywhere about method arrays and it doesn't do it like I want it to.

I don't want to make several methods and then save them in an array, I want to create methods in a loop, and I don't know how to do this.

I need it so I can make as many methods I want of this certain method, instead of writing 100 methods.

Comment: Err no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: First of all you cannot create even a normal method in a loop like that. Secondly you need to be more specific, what exactly you want to do. Keep aside the method for a while.

Comment: Why create duplicate method? I think its not possible in Java. You can call the same method several times.

Comment: And how do you intend to call these methods you're creating?

Comment: Why can't you just remove that method, and just let the `sysout` do its work?

Comment: Reason why i cant just remove that method is because obviously the syso isnt the only thing im doing in those methods

To Tudor, i intend on calling them in some way like this 
method[0]();
method[1]();
method[2]();

Comment: These things are not "obvious" to us. The more information you can supply, the better the answers will be.

Comment: Ye i see that, sorry for saying "obviously". But i intended to do alot more than just syso inside it. Anyways i had a brainfart and i realised what i could do, so i got my answer myself. 

I wanted to make an array of methods because in 5 methods i had 5 buffered images, But realised i could just make 1 method with a BufferedImageArray like this BufferedImage[]. 

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Are we talking about method reflection here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: Ok. Please answer your own question so that others know the issue is solved. Or accept Sumit's answer, which seems reasonable.